# onchange dropdownbox in html and php?

Tags: php, html, dropdownbox

Does anyone knows how to code a form with a dropdown where after selecting the options in the dropdown the form will display a certain layout depending on the chosen dropdown options?

For example, if i choose 4 in the dropdown list, the form should display 4 empty textboxes, but if i choose 2, the form will only display 2.

Comment: Take a look at [.change()](https://api.jquery.com/change/) jQuery's event. If you want to do it with php you need to create a form an submit it in order to show the text boxes.

Answer (score 0):

Check my [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/refojaravi/2/)!

Given some example HTML:

```
<select id='select'>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
<input id='a' class="input" hidden></input>
<input id='b' class="input" hidden></input>
<input id='c' class="input" hidden></input>
<input id='d' class="input" hidden></input>
```

Your solution could look something like this:

```
$('#select').change(function (evt) {
  var no_inputs = $(this).val();
  $('.input').each(function (i) {
    $(this).hide();
    if (i < no_inputs) {
      $(this).show();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: your code seems to work in ur JSBin but if i copied it over to my netbeans software and run it in IE or chrome,the codes doesnt seems to work. Any idea why?

Comment: @ayowhassup Have you included jQuery in your project? Have you in a document ready handler, `$(function() { /* insert code here */ }`?

Comment: <script>
    $(function() {
        $('#select').change(function(evt) {
            var no_inputs = $(this).val();
            $('.input').each(function(i) {
                $(this).hide();
                if (i < no_inputs) {
                    $(this).show();
                }
            });
        });

    });


</script>

Comment: Yes, have you included jQuery in your project? `<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>`